# Taylor expansion of expectation in financial modelling problem

Tags: probability, taylor-expansion, expected-value

Jin and Kawczak (2003) *"Birnbaum-Saunders and Lognormal Kernel Estimators for Modelling Durations in High Frequency Financial Data"* expanded as $$\mathbb{E}[\lambda_x^{-1} f(\lambda_x ) ]=\mu_x^{-1} f(\mu_x )+\frac{1}{2}\color{red}{\left(2x^{-3} f(x)-2x^{-2} f'(x)+x^{-1} f'' (x)\right)} V_\lambda$$
I know that the function is expanded through Taylor series. My question is which Taylor series is used for the red part? 
Here $\lambda_x$ is a lognormal random variable with $(\ln x, 2 \ln (1 + b))$, $V$ is variance, $\mu_x$ is mean and $b$ is constant.

Comment: You should introduce the topic, otherwise it is not understandable: what's $f?$ What are $\lambda_x, \mu_x, V_{\lambda}?$

Comment: I edited your question to improve the $\LaTeX$ formatting (i.e., add one) and make here easier to read (you may want to check the result). However, to make sense of the question, you may want to define $\lambda_x ,\mu_x$: what are they, with regard to $x$? And what are $V_\lambda$ and $b$? Without these 4 definitions, your question is absolutely unintelligible.

Comment: If $b$ is a constant, writing $o(b)$ is a very weird thing (That's $o(1)$, unless $b=0$ in which case, well... $o(b)$ means $0$.) And **what is $\lambda_x$?**

Comment: kindly answer the question, i have tried to make all possible suggested changes in the question to make question easy to understand.

Comment: What's the relation between the title (with $f(f(x))$) and the question?

Comment: Taylor series is again opened in a series that's why i thought.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't quite figure out what your question is saying, but I'll give an answer that will hopefully be useful in figuring out what's going on underneath.

Recall the Taylor expansion of the expectation:
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(x)]\approx f(\mathbb{E}[X]) + \frac{1}{2}f''(\mathbb{E}[X])\mathbb{V}[X]
$$
for some RV $X$.

Let us define $$ g(\lambda_x) = \lambda_x^{-1}f(\lambda_x) $$
Further, let $\mu=\mathbb{E}[\lambda_x]$ and $\sigma^2=\mathbb{V}[\lambda_x] $. Then:
$$ \mathbb{E}[g(\lambda_x)] \approx g(\mu) + \frac{g''(\mu)}{2}\sigma^2 $$
Notice that:
\begin{align}
g'(a)  &= a^{-1}f'(a) - a^{-2}f(a)\\
g''(a) &= 2a^{-3}f(a) - 2a^{-2}f'(a) + a^{-1}f''(a)
\end{align}
Thus, I get:
$$
\mathbb{E}[g(\lambda_x)] \approx \mu^{-1}f(\mu) + 
\frac{1}{2}\left(
2\mu^{-3}f(\mu) - 2\mu^{-2}f'(\mu) + \mu^{-1}f''(\mu)
\right)\sigma^2
$$
which is suspiciously close to the quantity in question.

Comment: can u give me some authentic reference for this?because your answer is not applicable on other such expansions...

Comment: @AngelAngel I don't know what you mean by authentic or "other such expansions". Look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70490/taking-the-expectation-of-taylor-series-especially-the-remainder?noredirect=1&lq=1) for a good discussion/more information.

Comment: kindly if u check above mentioned reference then other similar expansions do not gave same results by your helping material. for example check    A.14

Comment: kindly help me in this way...